# How to find this limit $\lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{n^{(1+sin((\pi*n)/2))/2}}{\sqrt(n)}$?

Tags: limits

I am struggling to find this limit:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{n^{(1+sin((\pi*n)/2))/2}}{\sqrt(n)}$$

Wolfram alpha failed.

Comment: Am I missing something - or - is it easy to subtract the power of minus a half created by the denominator from the exponent in the numerator - don't just rely on Wolfram!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence does not have a limit, as it varies between 0, 1 and $\inf$. You can see this from the fact that exponent $u$ in the numerator follows the sequence $\frac{1}{2}, 1, \frac{1}{2}, 0, \frac{1}{2}, 1, \frac{1}{2}, 0, \ldots$. For $u=1$ and $n\rightarrow\infty$, the sequence goes to infinity. For $u=\frac{1}{2}$, the expression limits to 1, for $u=0$, the limit is zero.